# How to find exception in C++Builder Release mode, but not Debug

Tags: exception, release, c++builder

C++Builder v10.4.2, CLang 64-bit compiler
Floating point error in Release mode, but not in Debug. It happens when a particular graph is called, when a particular user file is run in a simulation. This has happened in the past (different user file, same graph module), disappeared, now resurfaced. Troubleshooting by commenting out code gives nonsensical results, suggesting the problem is happening elsewhere - not in the graph modules.

Driving my crazy.

Are there any tools / switches / etc. in C++Builder that I might use to expose the problem in Release mode?

Any other suggestions for troubleshooting?

Follow up: I put identical source files into C++Builder 10.2.3, rebuilt, and it runs without errors.
Re-installed 10.4.2 and third party tools, rebuilt the project from scratch, still getting same errors with same files. Note that the project involves calculations with std::complex values, if that may be relevant.
Hate to abandon 10.4.2 (really like TwineCompile), but this is clearly unacceptable.

Thanks

Comment: The RTL in C++Builder/Delphi has some really wonky exception handling when it comes to floating-point errors. Have a look at things like [`SetExceptionMask()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.SetExceptionMask), [`Set8087CW()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Set8087CW), etc.

Comment: I was able to get the debugger to at least give a clue:  it gives a class $C0000090 floating point invalid operation at 0x00f5c4da, and it takes me to the CPU view -- which is meaningless to me.  Occasionally it will give a divide by zero error.  I should add that this happens in both 32 and 64 bit, and only in C++Builder 10.4.2  v10.2.3 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [madExcept](http://madshi.net/) or [Eurekalog](https://www.eurekalog.com/index.php), I believe both have free trials.